# Error in -train : invalid argument to unary operator

Tags: r, rpart

I am using R Studio and trying to knit a file. the code chunk below will run as the chunk but throws an error when I try to knit the file.

```
tree.corolla <- rpart(Price ~ ., data = toyota.corolla.df, control = rpart.control(maxdepth = 5), method = "anova")
```

The error I am getting is:

Error in -train : invalid argument to unary operator
Calls:  ... eval -> predict -> predict.rpart -> [ -> [.data.frame

I am using the ToyotaCorolla.csv dataset that is available here:

https://pitt.box.com/s/e0rhjtba8az85epqus9xu85e4q6zxuts

The entire code chunk is below:

```
#install.packages("rpart")
#install.packages("rpart.plot")
#install.packages("gbm")
#install.packages("randomForest")
#install.packages("dummies")
library(randomForest)
library(gbm)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(tree)
library(ISLR)
library(dummies)
library(adabag)
library(rpart) 
library(caret)
toyota.corolla.df <- read.csv("ToyotaCorolla.csv")
#View(toyota.corolla.df)
# randomly generate training and validation sets
toyota.corolla.df <- toyota.corolla.df[ , -c(1, 2, 5, 6)]

toyota.corolla.df <- cbind(toyota.corolla.df, dummy(toyota.corolla.df$Fuel_Type, sep = "_"))
toyota.corolla.df <- cbind(toyota.corolla.df, dummy(toyota.corolla.df$Color, sep = "_"))
toyota.corolla.df <- toyota.corolla.df[ , -c(4, 7)]
set.seed(123)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(toyota.corolla.df$Price, p = .60, list = FALSE)
training <- toyota.corolla.df[ inTraining,]
testing  <- toyota.corolla.df[-inTraining,]
tree.corolla <- rpart(Price ~ ., data = toyota.corolla.df, control = rpart.control(maxdepth = 5), method = "anova") 

summary(tree.corolla)
plot(tree.corolla)
text(tree.corolla,pretty=0)
cv.corolla=trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 10)
prp(tree.corolla, type = 1, extra = 1, split.font = 1, varlen = -10)
yhat=predict(tree.corolla,newdata=toyota.corolla.df[-train,])
corolla.test=toyota.corolla.df[-train,"Price"]
plot(yhat,corolla.test)
abline(0,1)
```